# Specify legend size in GetLegendGraphic

Tags: geoserver, wms, legend, getlegendgraphic

The WMS call `GetLegendGraphic` (in my case to Geoserver) returns a single image of icons and legends. How can I specify the width of the returned image? The `WIDTH` parameter is the width of the symbology icons, not the returned image.

The aim is to force word-wrapping of legend text for long layer names, so I hope that if the width can be specified, text will be wrapped.

I know I can get individual legend icons back via the `RULE` parameter, but would rather control the whole legend block if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the overall size of the legend cannot be forced, and there is no word-wrapping logic (only the labelling engine in the map supports word wrapping, the legend graphic builder is an entirely different animal).